# How to execute a function defined in plugin options

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, execution, execute

So there's probably a really simple piece of code I need here but I just can't for the life of me find it on google..

So I got a simple (modified) version of the jquery UI .selectmenu() plugin and I'm setting it up as follows:

```
    $("#actions").selectmenu({
        callback: function() {
            alert('something');
        }
    });
```

and in the plugin itself I have the following bit of code:

```
close: function(event, retainFocus) {
    var self = this, o = this.options;
    if(o.callback != false) {
        if($.isFunction(o.callback)) {

            // HERE I NEED TO EXECUTE THE CODE IN 'o.callback' ...... BUT HOW!??????

        }
    }
```

How the hell do I execute the alert('something'); from within the plugin. I give up. Somebody please help.

Albert

Answer (score 0):

yes you can trigger a callback function with .bind

heres a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/QJz5T/1/ just click "bar" to see what its doing

HTML (example):

```
<div id="foo">foo</div>
<div id="bar">bar</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#foo').bind('custom', function() {
    $(this).toggle();
    alert('foo');
});

$('#bar').click(function() {
    $('#foo').trigger('custom');
    alert('bar');
});
```

i hope this will help you understanding what you need/want to do with your code